# Update file content using a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, sed, grep, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` file, in which I have a docker images with its versioning tag, example `myrepo.com/myimage:1.0.1.0`. I want to write a bash script that receives the version number as a parameter and updates the version tag of the relevant image.

Currently I am using the below command to replace the version tag with the help of `grep` and `sed`, but I believe there should be a more efficient way for this. Any suggestions?

```sh
sedval='1.1.1.1'  # <-- new value

imageval=$(grep -i 'image: myrepo.com/myimage:' docker-compose.yml | cut -d ':' -f2,3)
imagename=$(grep -i 'image: myrepo.com/myimage:' docker-compose.yml | cut -d ':' -f2)
imageversion=$(grep -i 'image: myrepo.com/myimage:' docker-compose.yml | cut -d ':' -f3)
sed -i -e "s+$imageval+$imagename:$sedval+g" docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating YAML with line-oriented regex tools is generally not advisable. You should probably switch to a YAML-aware tool like `yq` for this.

There doesn't seem to be a reason you extract `imageversion`; you assign this variable, but never use it.  In fact, if you forgo the requirement to match case-insensitively, all you really need is

```
sed -i "s+\\(image: myrepo\\.com/myimage:\\)[.0-9]*+\\1$1+" docker-compose.yml
```

assuming (like you say in your question) the new version number is in `$1`, which is the first command-line argument to your script.

I don't think Docker allows you to use upper case; and if it does, you can replace `i` with `[Ii]`, `m` with `[Mm]`, etc.  Notice also how the literal dot needs to be backslash-escaped, strictly speaking.

Generally speaking, you can often replace `grep 'x' | sed 'y'` with `sed '/x/y'`; see also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) Also, the repeated `grep` could easily be refacored into a single `grep` with something like

```
imageval=$(grep -i 'image: myrepo.com/myimage:' docker-compose.yml)
imagever=${imageval##*:}
imagename=${imageval%:$imagever}
```

where the shell parameter substitutions are both simpler and more elegant as well as more efficient than repeatedly spawning `cut` in a separate process for this very simple string extraction task.

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose supports [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/). You could do the following:

```
 version: "3"
   services:
      myrepo:
       image: myrepo.com/myimage:${VERSION}
```

docker-compose looks for the VERSION environment variable and substitutes its value in the file. Run with:

```
export VERSION=1.1.1.1; docker-compose up
```